# How can I select a few records using the CONVERT()-function in where-clauses for a given DAY of DATETIME from a table with a million records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that uses the CONVERT()-function to fetch records for a specific DATE (day). I learned from SO-answers that CONVERT() should not be in where-clause when there are millions of records ([SQL query to select million records quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511249/sql-query-to-select-million-records-quickly)).

I am concerned about the speed of the query when we have a million records in the MOTRIP-table using the CONVERT() function in the where clause.

I seek advice whether it would be a good idea to place a "new date-only field" (TRIP_START_DATE) into the MOTRIP-table to eliminate using the CONVERT()-function in this query that needs the last trip of a specific DAY. ???

The MOTRIP-table has an INDEX on the DTTM_TRIP_START (smalldatetime) column AND an INDEX on the UID_CUSTOMER (int) column.

I use the CONVERT(DATE,DTTM_TRIP_START) function to examine trips that have taken place during a DAY to know the last trip of a day with other criteria.

```sql
DECLARE @UID_MOTRIP int = 409;
SELECT TOP (1)
       @UID_MOTRIP AS UID_MOTRIP,
       UID_MOTRIP AS TRIP_WITH_POST_UID,
       IIF(UID_INSPECTION_POST = 0, 1, 0) AS IS_POSTTRIP_MISSING
FROM MOTRIP
WHERE (UID_CUSTOMER = (SELECT UID_CUSTOMER
                       FROM MOTRIP
                       WHERE (UID_MOTRIP = @UID_MOTRIP)))
  AND (CONVERT(date, DTTM_TRIP_START) = (SELECT CONVERT(date, DTTM_TRIP_START)
                                         FROM MOTRIP
                                         WHERE (UID_MOTRIP = @jjUID_MOTRIP)))
ORDER BY DTTM_TRIP_START DESC;
```

My current "test" database has only 200 records in it and the result is instant.

I added a where-clause to limit the fetches based on the customer for MOTRIP=409 when thinking about a million records in the future.

Comment: The "better" performance change is more likely to switch those subqueries to a single one. I *assume* (as we have no sample data) that `DTTM_TRIP_START` is a date *and time* value? You note that it's a `smalldatetime`, but I've seen many people use such data types to store a *date* value (so the time portion is always midnight).

Comment: `WHERE (UID_CUSTOMER = (SELECT UID_CUSTOMER
                       FROM MOTRIP
                       WHERE (UID_MOTRIP = @jjUID_MOTRIP)))` why not just `WHERE UID_MOTRIP = @jjUID_MOTRIP` I think you have a long way to go before optimizing function calls becomes a concern

Comment: if you have a one row match which apparently you must have otherwise you'd get a subquery more than one row error, the match on function call won't matter

Comment: @siggemannen It appears that a customer can have multiple trips per day. Given some trip for a customer, the query selects the last trip for that customer on the same day, checking that that last trip has a "post-trip inspection". `UID_MOTRIP` appears to be the PK.

Comment: @TN hmm, that makes sense i guess, if that's what the query should be doing? but it's kinda backward to get the last trip from a specific trip me thinks since it does top 1?

Comment: @ThomA...the DTTM_TRIP_START returns 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' so YES it has a time value attached to the date. Thank you.

Comment: @siggemannen... The single original one row is to show the query fetch-logic to get to million records in the future.   I actually need a VIEW that can be filtered by UID_MOTRIP.  My problem anticipates the use of CONVERT()-function once the trips have actually been placed into the DB MOTRIP-table.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a **combined** index on `MOTRIP(UID_CUSTOMER, DTTM_TRIP_START)`, if that index (or a similar index starting with those two columns) does not already exist. Separate `UID_CUSTOMER` and `DTTM_TRIP_START` indexes not provide the same efficient access.

Once that index is in place, an efficient lookup can be achieved by calculating a start and end date/time range equal to:

- Range-start = 00:00 on the date of interest
- Range-end = 00:00 of the next day.

The range-start is *inclusive* and range-end is *exclusive*. This is a common practice for date/time range lookups. No date-only column is needed.

Finally, you can look up the required rows on matching `UID_CUSTOMER` and `DTTM_TRIP_START >= range-start` and `DTTM_TRIP_START < range-end`. Note the use of `<` for the *exclusive* end date/time. SQL server should perform a range seek on the index mentioned above.

I applied this logic in the modified query below. I also changed the dual subselects to a single join to eliminate duplication, and added qualifiers to all column references.

```
DECLARE @UID_MOTRIP int = 409;
SELECT TOP (1)
       @UID_MOTRIP AS UID_MOTRIP,
       M.UID_MOTRIP AS TRIP_WITH_POST_UID,
       IIF(M.UID_INSPECTION_POST = 0, 1, 0) AS M.IS_POSTTRIP_MISSING
FROM MOTRIP MRef
JOIN MOTRIP M
    ON M.UID_CUSTOMER = MRef.UID_CUSTOMER
    AND M.DTTM_TRIP_START >= CONVERT(date, MRef.DTTM_TRIP_START)
    AND M.DTTM_TRIP_START < DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(date, MRef.DTTM_TRIP_START))
WHERE MRef.UID_MOTRIP = @jjUID_MOTRIP
ORDER BY M.DTTM_TRIP_START DESC;
```

This could also be coded up as the logically identical:

```
DECLARE @UID_MOTRIP int = 409;
SELECT TOP (1)
       @UID_MOTRIP AS UID_MOTRIP,
       M.UID_MOTRIP AS TRIP_WITH_POST_UID,
       IIF(M.UID_INSPECTION_POST = 0, 1, 0) AS M.IS_POSTTRIP_MISSING
FROM (
    SELECT
        MRef.UID_CUSTOMER,
        CONVERT(date, MRef.DTTM_TRIP_START) AS RangeStart,
        DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(date, MRef.DTTM_TRIP_START)) AS RangeEnd
    FROM MOTRIP MRef
    WHERE MRef.UID_MOTRIP = @jjUID_MOTRIP
) MRef
JOIN MOTRIP M
    ON M.UID_CUSTOMER = MRef.UID_CUSTOMER
    AND M.DTTM_TRIP_START >= MRef.RangeStart
    AND M.DTTM_TRIP_START < MRef.RangeEnd
ORDER BY M.DTTM_TRIP_START DESC;
```